# Magento images not showing anywhere

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image-upload

I just installed a fresh copy of Magento 1.9.2.3.  Now my issue is when I try to upload any images, be it product, category, transactional email, ect. it gives me the little broken image placeholder.  Now the steps I have tried so far:

1. Changed \media folder to 777
2. Flushed all Cache (Magento and images)
3. Read endless questions on similar issues but to no avail.
4. This is happening in the frontend and Admin
5. I have checked the link it creates to the image and when I put that in the address bar it gives me a "404 not found" error.
6. I have checked that the image is indeed uploaded to the folder that the site is pointing to.

Note:  I have had Magento running on this server previously, but it is one to two versions older.

URL is http://southernperformanceparts.com - In case you want to take a look

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU2Zd.png)

Can anyone give me some direction here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a right problem.
Are the images set to 644?

You could change your `Uploader.php (lib/Varien/File)`
search for `"chmod($destinationFile, 0640);"` and change it to `0644`
and search for

`"if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0750, true)))"` and change it to `0755`

In the future the images should get the correct rights after uploading.